# Document library with infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a document library which has an infopath associated with it.

When I click on new button , it show popup with options for a brief before navigating to infopath form.

Is there any way in which this popup can be hidden?
[image: New button popup]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you add a infopath form as a content type to the library. If you want to have a form for the library, you will need to go Library settings> Form settings> use a custom form created in PowerApps. You will need to use PowerApps for a custom form
[image]

Comment: thanks for the inputs. But, it's a classic site and only infopath is allowed